# For a compact Hausdorff Space $X$, prove that $(X\backslash (p))\cup\{\infty\}\approxeq X$

Tags: general-topology

The title says it all- if you remove a point from a compact Hausdorff space and then "add the point back in" with the one point compactification, is it homeomorphic to the original space? This seems really intuitive (remove a point,  add it back, is the same as doing nothing) but I am unsure where to get started on proving this.

Comment: You don't only remove a point and add it back, you also, in general, change the topology. The open subsets might not be the same.

Comment: For instance $X-p$ is open in $X-p\cup\infty$, is it open in $X$? If yes, why?